# std::equal_range not working with strucutre having operator< defined

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, equal-range

I am trying to use `std::equal_range` with the structure below I have compilation error saying that `error: no match for ‘operator<’` .

```
 struct MyFoo {
    int     v_;
    string  n_;
    bool operator<(int v) const
    { return v_ < v;}
 };

 vector<MyFoo> data; 
 // data is sorted by int v_
 typedef vector<MyFoo>::iterator Ptr;
 std::pair< Ptr, Ptr > pr = std::equal_range(data.begin(), data.end(), 10);
```

I've looked into the template implementatino and what is failing is the following where `*it` is deferenging the iterator pointing to an object of MyFoo and `val_` is 10.

```
 if(*it < val_) {
  ...
 }
```

Why it is not working? I thought probably because it is trying to call the the global `operator<`  that is not defined, but since I defined it as class member that should not be a problem, isn't it?

Comment: `bool operator(int v) const` - [Umm](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1faff8f605dbe6fb)

Comment: typo..fixed the post..error is really that one...

Comment: Sure `someMyFoo < someInt` will work, but not `someInt < someMyFoo`.

Comment: ..so better to have a global operator for both cases...I get confused as I was reading only at the code of lower_bound while there is also upper_bound that needs the other way around...

Comment: To elaborate on the comment from chris: you need a `bool operator < (int i, MyFoo &f)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide non-member comparison operators :

```
 bool operator<(int v, const MyFoo& foo)
 { 
   return foo.v_ < v;
 }

 bool operator<(const MyFoo& foo, int v)
 {
   return v < foo;
 }
```

Alternatively, you can provide a conversion operator to `int` :

```
operator int() cont {return v_;}
```

Which is probably unwanted, since the compiler will be able to perform silent conversions in other places of your code.

Answer (score 1):

As an other alternative: provide

```
bool operator<(const MyFoo& rhs) const { return v_ < rhs.v_; }
```

And use `std::equal_range` on a dummy object with correct `v_` as:

```
std::pair<Ptr, Ptr> pr = std::equal_range(data.begin(), data.end(), MyFoo{10, ""});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be having trouble because the std::equal_range implementation uses std::less. This is going to try to convert your MyFoo to an int to do the comparison, rather than just using an operator<() overload. Try adding this to your MyFoo class...

```
operator int() const
{
    return v_;
}
```